# angular 2 - how do I iterate through a JSON response that contains an object which contains an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am using a web api that my friend created, and here is a sample response:

```
{
  types: [
    {
      id: 1,
      contents: [
        {
          id: 1001,
          perishable: 0
        },
        {
          id: 1002,
          perishable: 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So if I get a response back that has 3 types of things in it, and each of those types has 3 contents, how can I use a repeater in this scenario below?  I am able to get the type id correctly, but I am having trouble with repeating over the contents.

```
<div *ngFor="let type of response.types">
  <h2>{{type.id}}</h2>
  <!-- here I want to show basically divs for each of the objects in contents -->
  <div *ngFor="what should I do here?">
    <p>{{content.id}}</p>
    <p>{{content.perishable}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="let type of response.types">
  <h2>{{type.id}}</h2>

       <div *ngFor="let content of type.contents">
            <p>{{content.id}}</p>
            <p>{{content.perishable}}</p>
        </div>

</div>
```